# C# Remove Square Brackets From Array

Tags: c#, json.net

I am building a Web API and am working account to the exact requirements set out by the external company who will be retrieving the data from the API via a GET request. One requirement is to have square brackets enclosing arrays within the return to be removed. Below is an example of what I currently have - the Departments of Religions, Languages and History are enclosed in square brackets;

```
{
    "roles": [
        [
            "STUDENT",
            "Undergraduate",
            3,
            [
                "History",
                "Languages",
                "Religions"
            ],
            "GIBSON, David Test",
            666778
        ]
    ]
}
```

What they require is for the return to look like this;

```
{
  "roles": [
    [
      "STUDENT",
      "Undergraduate",
      3,
      "History",
      "Languages",
      "Religions",
      "GIBSON, David Test",
      666778
    ]
  ]
}
```

Not sure if this will help, but the three Departments above are an array called deptarray i.e. if a student belongs to more than one department, list those departments in the return as an array;

```
var deptarray = jArr.Distinct();

if (deptarray.Count() > 1) studentList[0][i] = new JArray(deptarray);
```

I would be grateful for any help in removing the square bracket enclosures and just having the departments in double quotes.

Comment: I'm guessing from `JArray` that you're using Json.NET?

Comment: You don't need to remove the brackets, you just need to create the array that contains `"Student","Undergrad", etc.` differently. Are you sure you have this correct? If you do what you're suggesting, and assuming the number of departments is variable, how will one tell the difference between a department and the name that follows the department list?

Comment: @stuartd thank you for responding - yes, that's right, I'm using Json.NET.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thank you for taking time to check out the question. The external company will not need to tell the difference between the department list the the other student data. Every bit of student data they will read is referred to as a 'role' so when they send a GET request for any particular student, they want their data listed in the above format and each line (e.g. department, year, student number etc) is referred to as a 'role'. So for the above student example, they will have 8 roles i.e. a role created for each row in the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you never stop. This is your code that you have to add to your ADO.net

```
   var roles = JArray.From(studentRoles);

    if (roles.Count() > 1)
    {   
         var newArr = new JArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < roles[0].Count(); j++)
        {
            var jArr = new JArray();
            for (var i = 1; i < roles.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i == 1) jArr = new JArray { roles[0][j] };
                jArr.Add(roles[i][j]);
            }
 
            var arr = jArr.Distinct();

            if (arr.Count() > 1)
                foreach (var item in arr)
                {
                    newArr.Add(item);
                }
            else newArr.Add(arr.First());
                
            }
       }
         roles=newArr;
     }

var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { roles = roles 
});
```

Comment: Ha! Good to see you again my friend :). I promise I'll stop soon haha. Thank you again for your help. Let me look at this and get back to you.

Comment: I owe you a drink, or four? That's done EXACTLY what I was needing. Thank you so much Serge! You've been my hero this week haha! :)

Comment: @GBM You are welcome!. Pls be honest now and tell if there is something  that you still need to change.

Comment: LOL! I promise there's nothing else :) well at least not relating to the format of the data, ha! You've been a gent and I appreciate you! Thanks again for all your help!